# Remote power shell through load balancer

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access, exchange-2013, remote

I want to connect to exchange server via remote Powershell. When I connect directly with server URL I am able to create the session. But in the production I have many instances of exchange server, So I have created loa balancer for them and tried to connect with load balancer URL through remote Powershell. But I am getting

**Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: The computer is unknown to Kerberos. Verify that the computer exists on the network, that the name provided is spelled correctly, and that the Kerberos configuration for accessing the computer is correct. The most common Kerberos configuration issue is that an SPN with the format HTTP/ is not configured for the target. If Kerberos is not required, specify the Negotiate authentication mechanism and resubmit the operation. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.**

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to connect with a load balancer?  It's definitely going to cause Kerberos problems, and while you could move down to NTLM, I wouldn't.  This article might help with understanding Kerberos. https://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/the-biggest-mistake-serviceprincipalname-s

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use IP address to connect to remote powershell? Are you able to telnet to port which you used?

In addition, you can have a read of [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc794747(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article to learn a bit more about selective trusts and whether or not it’s affecting you.

A similar [case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37da27bb-a1f0-4ec4-bc67-f94c9150cbe6/winrm-cannot-process-the-request-the-following-error-occured-while-using-kerberos-authentication?forum=winserverManagement) for your reference.